# Using NHibernate is it possible to create different database column(field) names based on language?

Tags: database, nhibernate, database-design, language-agnostic, internationalization

Something came up at work today and I'm not sure how you would go about it. Essentially, we have an application that is making use of NHibernate. Currently, we are using Fluent NHibernate and exporting the schema directly from the domain using ExportSchema. The column names are in English.

During some discussions today, it came out that as well as internationalizing the data there is an idea of getting the column names to be also in the language of the install.

So for example, if the database was deployed to an English speaking country the column names would be in English and if it was deployed to a francophone country the column names would be in French.

The theory seemed to be such that if a user wanted to write queries against the datastore they would be able to query using column names based in their native language. (assume they are named descriptively).

I can't say that I have come across this before and I am intrigued how you would go about it? Also, even though I mention NHibernate if there are other options please feel free to mention them.

Thanks

Comment: Your column names are part of your sourcecode, are you writing all you sourcecode in the local language of the users? You end up with a lot of programmes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use resource files for each languauge you want to support and in your fluent mappings refer to these resources rather than hard coded strings.  So an example mapping would looking something like this:

```
public OrderMap()
{
    CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("HelloWorldGlobed.myRes",typeof(OrderMap).Assembly);

    DynamicUpdate();
    Table(rm.GetString("ORDER_TABLE_NAME",culture));
    Id(x => x.Id, rm.GetString("ORDER_ID",culture));
    Map(x => x.Name, rm.GetString("ORDER_NAME",culture));
}
```

The above is just a simple example and I have not tested this but this gives you an idea of how you would do this using resources.  You would probably want to consolidate the retriaval of the `CultureInfo` object and the `ResourceManager` object in a static class or something.

Here is also an example of using resources in C#:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5208/MultiLanguage-Applications

Comment: Thanks for that it confirms some of the thoughts I was having. However, I'm not so sure of the practicalities of doing this from a maintenance / testing point of view.